# UWP App with UI from a dll and not the mainpage

Tags: uwp

I have a DLL that provides all the necessary UI. I am trying to wrap this into a UWP app and add some extra MS Store functionality. I started with the C# Blank App template. The problem is that this launches a MainPage and then the UI I want from the DLL opens up. Is there a way to not have the MainPage start at all?

Comment: There have to be a startup page in the main Window. If you wants to show your own page at the beginning, navigate to `App.xaml.cs` file, find the `onlaunched` event, go to `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments); `, change the `MainPage` to the page you want to use.

Comment: The DLL already has its own Window and not a page. So, I am looking for a way to launch this Window instead of the default Window that comes with the blank app template.

Comment: UWP is using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Window` class as the main window in the `onlaunch` event. If you window Inherits from this class then you could try to directly use it. Can't guarantee this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Win UI 3 is more modern than UWP apps. So I tried it and it allows to launch the UI app with custom window (the default template code creates a main window, but there is no need to use it). So, while this is not the answer for UWP, perhaps it is a wrong question for what I need to accomplish.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You could accept your reply and this could help others who have the same question.